# How to slide the outer 2 columns under the centre column using HTML and CSS only?

Tags: css, z-index, html

First see http://jsfiddle.net/b2BpB/15/

3 columns, aligned to the top of a container which is centred on the page.  When the browser window is wider than the container - the example above is good.

When you shrink the width of the browser window - the columns start to stack down the page.

Question: How can I make it so that the outer two columns have a z-index lower then the centre column, so that when the browser window is squeezed, width-wise, instead of the columns stacking down the page, the outer columns slide under (behind) the centre column?

Note: I need to keep the present behaviours.  3 divs align to top of container.  3 divs grow / shrink to fit their contents (can't use fixed width, hight divs for the columns)

---

### --added 19 April 2010 am UK--

This one seems to be stumping everyone - I've added a couple of more tags to see if anyone else can figure it out.

It may help me & others even if you post your initial ideas and explain why they wont work in this instance - to help avoid dead ends.

One avenue I looked at is using iframes instead of divs - but auto resizing iframes in a cross-domain application requires some exotic javascript.  I would like to avoid javascript, let alone this cross domain hack. - I think this is a dead end - unless you know otherwise.

### Thanks in advance...

### --added 19 April 2010 13:44 UK--

@RoToRa - here I get absolute top positioning, divs size to fit content & divs sliding under the main centre div with no stacking down the page as the window is squeezed:

http://jsfiddle.net/qr7WB/

I have used inline style - but this is easy to extract to the CSS file - if I ever get it to do what I want.

If I can just get the left & right divs to but up to the centre div - only sliding under when the browser window forces them to, then bingo!

In terms of the application:  I want a 3 col web site.  The centre col holds the main content and I want it to take precedent.  The outside columns are for subordinate content and ads.

Answer (score 0):

First off: This isn't an answer, however I have several points and it's more readable as an answer.

I don't think what you want is possible. Having elements slide under each other is normally something one want to avoid, so it's not a "standard behavior" of CSS.

You'd have to use absolute positioning to have elements overlap each other, but then you can't have the elements adjust width and height to their contents.

The best I can think of is JavaScript, which could be based on the existing layout (so that it would still be displayed without JavaScript), and just "kick in", when the elements need to overlap. However that wouldn't be a simple script to write, because calculating the correct width it needs to react too, isn't simple.

Another alternative could be [CSS 3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), which allow you define different CSS rules based on window size, however that would require you to know at exactly which width you want the change.

As I mentioned having elements overlap - especially when they contain text, which one would expect to be able to read - is something one usually tries to avoid. Maybe you should describe your exact scenario (which elements contain which kind of information, and why it's ok for them to overlap) instead of your perceived solution, then it may be possible to suggest alternatives.

BTW I can't see how iframes would have to do with problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I think I may well have to give in and use javascript in the end.  I have got a little closer on my own and will post my latest jsfiddle next.

Answer (score 0):

Do You mean like this?

#### Example Fiddle : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/hbquR/)

if that's it it will depend on what widths you can or can't set, but if that's the idea more specs would help

It's all floated or inline-block, no absolute positioning so flow should remain to allow for footers to follow.. let me know!

#### Updated fiddle per comments : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/hbquR/3/)

Comment: Can you make it so that the left and right columns sit adjacent to the centre column.  The outside columns are to only slide under the centre column when the browser window size forces them to?

Comment: In your fiddle above - the left and right colums align to the left and right edge of the window respectively.  I want the right edged of the left column to sit adjacent to the left edge of the centre column.  The right column to mirror this.  Of course that is when the window size is wider than the (total width of all 3 columns).  When the browser window width < (total width of all 3 columns) then the outer columns start to slide under the centre column as if the window edges were pushing them.

Comment: Also - noticed in your example - if you squeeze the window enough, then the 3rd column stacked down the page - pushing the footer down.  This I'd want to avoid.

Comment: @tur130 which columns do you know the width of, if any? e.g is there a min-width for the center column or a fixed width wrapper? I did say in my answer it would be width dependant, this was just an idea - for example the center column would need to be at least (min-width) 1px wider than the 2 x sides or of course they will continue to drop if squeezed to much, eventually, it seems a bit odd to want to narrow the window that far LOL

Comment: updated fiddle added to answer - with wrapper widths made small enough to test, showing columns adjacent to center until window shrunk, because the center has a min-width greater than the sum of two sides the sides should no longer drop

Comment: All 3 columns will hold content that will define their dimensions at run time.  E.g. the may all hold picture, text, iframes...

Comment: For arument sake lets say I put a picture in each column (3 pictures) 1st col 75px wide, Middle column 500px wide and 3rd column 50px wide.  Then the columns need to auto-size to their contained pictures.  Unless the browser refresh is pressed and different content is served, then the column widts are to remain static.  When the browser window width is reduced, the columns should not re-size.  Does this make sense?